# Javascript String changes when Converted to Date()

Tags: javascript

I have run into a really weird problem.

I have two Javascript string variables which get their data from two text boxes.

The third string is pulled from the table cell. However, when it is converted to a Javascript Date() its date changes. I have no idea why this happening.

I will comment by code to help explain what is going on.

```
//get the text from the first textbox (from date)
var valueFrom = document.getElementById('selected-submittedDate-from').value;
                //convert the string into the right format              
                var formatDateString = function (unformatted) {
                    var parts = unformatted.split('-');
                    return parts[1] + '/' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[0];
                };
                var formattedDateFrom = formatDateString(valueFrom);

    //get the text from the second textbox (to date)
//convert the string into the right format
                var valueTo = document.getElementById('selected-submittedDate-to').value;
                var formatDateStringTo = function (unformatted) {
                    var parts = unformatted.split('-');
                    return parts[1] + '/' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[0];
                };
                var formattedDateTo = formatDateStringTo(valueTo);

//just make some new variables and set the formatted dates to them
                // date from, date to
                var dateFrom = formattedDateFrom;
                var dateTo = formattedDateTo;

//get the table row, then get the table cell,
                var TableRow = document.getElementById("applicant_data");
                var TableCells = TableRow.getElementsByTagName("td");

                // get the table cell[6] which is the date
                var check = TableCells[6].innerText;
                //convert it to a string (i think it is anyways?)
                var dateCheck = check.toString();

         // remove the slashes in the strings
                var d1 = dateFrom.split("/");
                var d2 = dateTo.split("/");
                var c = dateCheck.split("/");

        //log for testing
                console.log(d1);
                console.log(d2);
                console.log(c);

        //convert the strings into dates and set them as a new variable
                var from = new Date(d1[2], d1[1]-1, d1[0]);
                var to = new Date(d2[2], d2[1]-1, d2[0]);
                var check1 = new Date(c[2], c[1]-1, c[0]);

         //log them out again
                console.log(from);
                console.log(to);
                console.log(check1);
```

**The issue is with my output, look at this:**

```
["03", "04", "2014"]
["03", "05", "2014"]
["08", "19", "2013"]
Thu Apr 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Sat May 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

//this date below should be August 19 2013......
Tue Jul 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

How is this happening?!???!? The third date is literally changing.

Comment: Use `YYYY-MM-DD` if you can help it; it’s unambiguous.

Comment: When all else fails, [read the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1). :-) The format for creating a Date object is `new Date (year, month, date)` where months are zero indexed (i.e. 0 == January, 11 == December). The OP is using `year, day, month`. Use `new Date(s[2], --s[0], s[1])`.

Comment: Oh, and none of the converted dates are correct. e.g. 3/4/2014 in US format is 4 March, not 3 April and 3/5/2014 is 5 March, not 3 May.

Answer (score 3):

19 is converted to a month instead of 8 and by the looks of it, it does <strike>a modulo operation. 19%12 = 7</strike> a subtraction: 19 - 12 = 7 hence July. You may want to rearrange your date, otherwise it's the same case for the first 2. In other words, swap the month and day in your `new Date` call.

**More details**+(correction on earlier mistake):

`var check1 = new Date(c[2], c[1]-1, c[0]);`

In the code above, what you need to do is swap the last two so you have:

`var check1 = new Date(c[2], c[0]-1, c[1]);`

The function is expecting you to give the year, then month and day.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm not sure how to fix it. Could you help me out? I tried changing the values where it creates the date and it changed the year to 2086 but I'm not sure what the proper way to do it is.

Comment: FYI not modulo, it's subtraction.  Think of it as number of months rolling over the number of months in a year.  24 would end up as December of the following year (24 - 12 = 12 month 12, not 0).